# Laravel : OVH Hosting SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, connection

I'm trying to migrate a website i've developped on an OVH Server. 
But i'm blocked with a MySQL Error : 
[image]

On my Local Environment (and local variables : localhost, dbname, user, pass) it works fine. But on my OVH environment it doesn't with those following variables :

.env file
[image: .env variables]
database.php file
[image: database.php variables]

The thing i don't understand is that on my local Environment with my OVH variables it works. So i think there is a thing i miss on m
y OVH environment.

I'm on MySQL 5.6
and my composer.json
[image: composer.json]

I've searched on many forums, but most of them were about a local Environment

Thank's in advance. 
Cheers,

Comment: Maybe clearing cache will help

Comment: It works .. ahah thanks a lot man ! (i'm a newbie in Laravel)